# I get an error that says "your day value is invalid"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

So, basically the code below is to delete the current trigger and set a new trigger with the same function and the new date when the conditions are met.
However, when i tried to run the script I get an error of "Your day value is invalid." at the line ".create".

I have tried logger.log my "now" variable which is supposedly to be my new date and it popped up like this "Sun Dec 08 08:44:12 GMT+08:00 2019" which I assumed to be the correct date.

```js
function setTriggerCycle2() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss2 = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var fR1 = ss2.getSheetByName("Auto9 (LUDY) Carbon Treatment Checklist");
  var ranges = fR1.getRange(3, 1, fR1.getLastRow(), 32).getValues();


  ranges.forEach(function(row, i) {


    var CuTankNo = row[2];
    var DateSubmitted = row[0];
    var EmailSent = row[9];
    var triggerSetted = row[8];
    var now = new Date();
    now.setHours(now.getHours() + 3984)

    if (CuTankNo == "Cu Tank #2 Pos #45 & 48") {

      if (triggerSetted == "") {

        var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
        for (var i in triggers) {

          if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "sendEmailCuTank2") {

            ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);


          }

          Logger.log(now);

          ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmailCuTank2')
            .timeBased()
            .atDate(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay())
            .create();

          fR1.getRange(i + 3, 9).setValue("Trigger_Setted");


        }


      }

    }

  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `.atDate(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay())` Instead of `getDay()` use `getDate()`

- `getDay()` returns the day of the week, 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday and so on.
- `getDate()` returns the day of the month, 1 for the first day, 2 for the second day, and so on.